# asp.net chunked HTML5 video streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video, http-headers

I am using an asp.net ashx web handler to respond to video streaming requests from a HTML5 video control on a .aspx page. If the request has a 'Range' header, the handler will return the file using HTTP 206 partial content response. This works great in Google Chrome but Internet Explorer never has a 'Range' header included in it's request and as such I cannot determine the start/end of the byte array to respond with. The page will download the entire video with a HTTP 200 response before starting to play.

How can I get Internet Explorer to stream the video file (h.264 encoded mp4)? Any advice on streaming content in asp.net is appreciated.

a section from the existing .ashx web handler:

```
// response headers
context.Response.Headers["AcceptRanges"] = "bytes";
context.Response.Headers["ContentDisposition"] = "attachment;filename=" + fName;
context.Response.ContentType = fMime;
context.Response.Headers["ContentLength"] = fLength.ToString();
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;

if (context.Request.Headers["Range"] != null)
{
    // range request
    var match = Regex.Match(context.Request.Headers["Range"], @"bytes=(\d*)-(\d*)");
    startIndex = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    responseLength = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value == string.Empty ? fLength.ToString() : match.Groups[2].Value) - startIndex;
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    context.Response.Headers["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + startIndex + "-" + (startIndex + responseLength - 1) + "/" + fLength;
}

using (SqlFileStream sfs = new SqlFileStream(filePath, objContext, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.None, 0))
{
    sfs.Seek(startIndex, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = sfs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    while (bytesRead == buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: It is a good code to serve video. Thanks!